# jQuery on change, bound to document but element in third parameter will give empty value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the fiddle for the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/PdA4W/4/

Alert is empty (no value), when the select changes.

This is, I think because I have this line:

```
$(document).on('change', '.variant', function()
```

Now I cannot do it differently, according to my previous question:

[Appended select with jQuery, delegate/on event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791667/appended-select-with-jquery-delegate-on-event-not-working?noredirect=1)

I need to do it this way, because that I am cloning the variant div element each time you press Add

So how can I obtain the current selected option value in the select that are changing?

Comment: Please post your relevant html and js in the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add a change handler to a `<div>` not `<select>`

Modify the selector to target the `<select>`

```
$(document).on('change', '.variant select.quantity', function(){
     alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PdA4W/5/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$(document).on('change', '.variant', function(){
```

to

```
$(document).on('change', '.quantity', function(){
```

DIV doesn't listen to jQuery's 'change' event in the way you're thinking; only SELECT elements (and I think a couple other elements) do.  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The change is in quantity. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/JY3fC/

```
    $(function(){
        $('.add_variant').on('click', function(){
            var $orig = $('.variants div:first').clone();

            $('.variants').append($orig);
        });
        $(document).on('change', '.quantity', function(){
            alert( $(this).val() );
        });
    });
```